# Referencing next row in the dataframe by adding variable to index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to following code to loop through my dataframe :

```
for ind in df_delta.index:
[some code here]

   i = 0 
        while(df_delta['Rounded_Time'][ind+i] <= my_timer):
            print('Here')
            i += 1
```

Rounded_Time contains a time series in seconds. I am trying access those values and compare against the my_timer and do some operation in the middle. For some reason I keep getting Key Error [KeyError: 1921] whenever it goes to the second while iteration. Looks I can not access next few rows by adding i to index (ind). How can I fix this ?

Comment: what happens if `ind+i > len(df_delta)`? That is, `my_timer` is larger than all `df_delta['Rounded_Time']`?

Comment: my_timer would always be higher than values I am accessing in the dataframe by providing the index location

Comment: that's the problem, imagine `my_timer=np.inf`, then `i` would increase indefinitely, exceeding the number of element in `df_delta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was able to resolve this. The issue was my code was accessing the index that did not exist (because I had filtered some of the row before so those indices were missing), hence the key error. I just did following to reset the index, and it works fine now:

```
df_delta.reset_index(inplace=True)
```